# IE Conditional in Sass

Tags: css, class, nested

### Question

I use Paul Irish's IE Conditional Comments trick to target different versions of IE. In sass how do I apply one of these classes when nested in another class.

```
.container{
    // I need to put a ie8 specific style here which is a .ie8 class applied to the body
}
```

I'd like to avoid doing this if possible (it's nice to be able to keep the properties together):

```
.container{}
.ie8{
    .container{}
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post what you expect the outputted CSS to look like? This would help make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for - using [SASS's parent selector "&"](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector), you can do this:

```
.container {
    .ie8 & {
        // ie8 specific styles here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear as to what you are trying to do specifically. But If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to, then you could use a variable.

For example, lets say you only want to have your font color red in IE. You could do something like this.. Although I don't see how using SASS would be all that beneficial in this use case, unless of course you are trying to do something different.

**SASS:**
*You can test this at:* http://sassmeister.com/

```
$ieEightAndNine: "\0/";
.container {
   color:unquote(red + $ieEightAndNine);
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  color: red\0/;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**TEST IN CHROME VS IE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3G48v/

Comment: Hi Kris, I tried your solution and it works fine but what beats me is how it is working, I mean when I write a Sencha Touch application CSS is generated even before we open the webpage and after that it there is no role of the sass files in there, but how come this solution works depending on the browser.

Comment: @kapilchhattani, Basically it works cause IE 8 and 9 allows the characters and will still process the css, while other browsers won't. In my opinion hacks are not ideal, and I would use conditional statements if specific IE targeting is needed. Here is some reading ... http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/ie7-only-css-hacks/ .. and .. http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/